# Decay of smooth functions around their boundary

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

If $f\in{\cal C}^\infty({\bf R}^n)$ and $(x_k)_k$ is a converging sequence with $d(x_k,{\rm supp}(f)^C)\le 1/k$, does $k^N f(x_k)$ converge to $0$ then for any fixed $N>0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the sequence converges to $x_0\in \partial \text{supp} (f)$. Since all derivatives exist and are bounded in a neighborhood of $x_0$, the Taylor expansion with remainder tells us that, for a fixed $a>0$ and $N>0$, $f(x)=o(|x-y|^N)$ for every $x\in (x_0-a, x_0+a)$ and $y\in \partial \text{supp}(f)$. Now set $x=x_k$ and $y=y_k$ such that $|x_k-y_k|=\text{dist}(x_k, \text{supp}(f)^c)$. This is your claim.